# Creating an [Overlay, Alert] functionality in flutter

Tags: flutter

I want to create UI functionality in Flutter. I am not able to do that I need help. Here is the video example [Video](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/105051121/230849952-f99beebb-fb76-4c58-ae46-47153feeb939.webm). I point of the click could be any positions of the screen.

I need help to do that. I tried with overlay.

Comment: Please add some codes to the question that you've been trying, then someone will help.

Comment: It is more like custom tooltip

Answer (score 0):

To show an alert dialog in Flutter, you can use the `showDialog()` method.
Here is an example in which we show an alert dialog when tap on floating action button.

```
FloatingActionButton(
    onPressed: () {
        showDialog(
            context: context,
            builder: (_) => AlertDialog(
                title: Text('Your Title'),
                content: Text('The content of the dialog. It could be any widget'),
            ),
          );
        },
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
    )
);
```